# How to turn this javadoc warning off: @return tag has no arguments

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I don't want to have to write a description for the @return javadoc tag. How do I turn that off on my maven pom.xml?

Comment: If you didn't want to write a description for the return value, why didn't you just leave out the `@return` tags?

Comment: That's it Mike. Feel free to write an answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, the solution is to leave out the empty `@return` tags. ;-)

Sorry I don't have a 'magic' `pom.xml` answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Mike has it I believe.  More javadoc information can be found here.  I did not see any options which you could use to remove this specific warning.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDGADED *[updated to Java 8]*